# Javascript - Which framework to build scrollable map with item selection?

Tags: jquery, html, sencha-touch, html5-canvas

I need to scroll a large map area on a mobile device website, and be able to select PNG or vector images on the map, like this:

[image]

What would be the simplest method? HTML5, jQuery, Sencha Touch, or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML5 canvas you can scroll like this:

**JS:**

```
var img = new Image();  
img.src = 'image.jpg'; 

var w = $(window).outerWidth();
var h = $(window).height();

var addit = -1;
var scrollSpeed = 10; 
var current = 0;

ctx = document.getElementById('canvas1').getContext('2d');

var init = setInterval(function() {
               current += addit;
               ctx.drawImage(img,current,0, w, h);
           }, scrollSpeed);
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1784px" height="534px"></canvas>
```